# How to change themes in vs code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, themes

I have installed a theme from extension in vs code but it's not changing.is there anything need to enable apart from extension enables.
looking for the answer

Comment: Press "F1" and select "Preferences: Color theme", then choose

Answer (score 0):

Settings->Then press on 'Color Theme',it should be there if u installed it.[image]

Comment: how to add an additional theme. I installed vs code icon theme a material theme but how to enable those

Comment: If you install the theme, thats how you enable it. You go to 'Color Theme' and select your teme ,it should be there .If you didn't install the theme you have to go to extensions on your VS Code, in the search bar use -    '  theme : the theme you want'  https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/themes